# Capistrano error: Host does not exist / svn: Connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, deployment

I'm running from a Windows Vista machine using:

- The latest rails (as of Jan 2. 2010),
- Capistrano 2.5.10,
- Subversive plugin, and
- TortoiseSVN

So far, I have:

- created the remote repository,
- created ssh keys, and
- edited the TortoiseSVN config file.

(I'm not sure if I’ve left out anything.)

Here’s the error message I get when I try to deploy using Capistrano:

```
* executing `deploy:cold'

  * executing `deploy:update'

 ** transaction: start

  * executing `deploy:update_code'

    executing locally: "svn info svn+ssh://mydomain.com/home/45454/data/svn/repository/  -rHEAD"

checking for svn... yes

Unable to open connection:

Host does not exist

svn: Connection closed unexpectedly

*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back

  * executing "rm -rf /home/45454/containers/rails/wcn/releases/20091230175413; true"

    servers: ["mydomain.com"]

    [mydomain.com] executing command

    command finished

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/subversion.rb:58:in `query_revision': tried to run `svn info svn+ssh://mydomain.com/home/45454/data/svn/repository/  -rHEAD' and got unexpected result "" (RuntimeError)

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:35:in `send'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:35:in `method_missing'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:63:in `local'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/base.rb:35:in `method_missing'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:38:in `load'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:87:in `call'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:87:in `fetch'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:110:in `protect'

                 ... 38 levels...

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'

                from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.10/bin/cap:4

                from C:/Ruby/bin/cap:19:in `load'

                from C:/Ruby/bin/cap:19
```

Any ideas on what I should try next?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when svn goes to checkout the code it can't either resolve the hostname as defined by `:repository` or it can't ssh into "mydomain.com".

> ```
> executing locally: "svn info svn+ssh://mydomain.com/home/45454/data/svn/repository/  -rHEAD"
> ```
>
> checking for svn... yes
>
> **Unable to open connection:
> Host does not existsvn: Connection closed unexpectedly**

If you're deploying to your own Windows machine, try just using a [local svn reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls).